# Load a specific sprite by name from a SpriteSheet with Resources.Load

Tags: unity, c#, spritesheet

I want to avoid loading all the sprites from a sprite sheet into a dictionary. Is there a way to access the specific sprite inside the sheet. Right now I'm using this code :

```
 prefabImage.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(spritePath+spriteName);
```

But this loads a single sprite. Can I change spritePath to somehow point inside the sprite sheet?

Comment: Have a look here http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1175266/getting-single-sprite-from-a-sprite-multiple.html if it works, paste the solution as an answer for future reference in case the link dries up. I would but it's not my solution so I don't deserve credit.